# Flask passing in query string

Tags: python, function, flask

Fairly new to flask. Don't know how it works properly. However what I'm trying to do is using dryscrape module I'm trying to query a webpage. Using flask for my own front end.
However I am having trouble passing in my query string.
So what I'm trying to do is.

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getIndex():
    query = request.form.get('query')
    return render_template('index.html',query=query),query
```

using the "query" I want to continue using this into my other functions like this

```
@app.route("/search_info")
def search_info():
    string = getIndex()[1] ***# Here I'm having the issue. I'm trying to get the query string here and follow the proccess.*** 
    print string
    sess = dryscrape.Session(base_url='http://www.watchfreemovies.ch/')
    sleep(4)
    sess.visit('/')
    search_index = sess.at_xpath('//*[@name="search_keywords"]')
    search_index.set(string)
    sleep(4)
    sess.render('inputz.png')
    search_index.form().submit()
```

As commented. I'm trying to pass in my query string into my new function and use dryscrape to do rest of the stuff. However I'm doing something wrong. It doesn't work. Need help!

Comment: Check out [variable rules](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#variable-rules)

Comment: `request.form` reads from the post body. `request.args` reads from the query string.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the query string to be available across requests you need to store it somewhere on either the client side or server side. [Flask-Session](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/) will handle this for you on the server side and is probably the simplest solution. You'll need a somewhere to store the session data and there are various different option for this, including file system.

**Example:**

```
from flask import Flask, session
from flask.ext.session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)
# Check Configuration section for more details
SESSION_TYPE = 'filesystem'
app.config.from_object(__name__)
Session(app)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getIndex():
    query = request.form.get('query')
    session['query'] = query
    return render_template('index.html',query=query),query

@app.route("/search_info")
def search_info():
    query = session.get('query')
    print query
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your concept of HTTP request and respond is not clear. Let me assume some usecase to explain.

1. When you request `your.domain/search_info`, flask will run `search_info()` function
2. And then,  flask will run another function `getIndex()` in `search_info()` line 1 `string = getIndex()[1]`
3. Based on `string = getIndex()[1]`, flask will send a GET query to `your.domain/`, and run `getIndex()`
4. However, flask will query NOTHING when it sent GET query.
5. Because `request.form.get('query')` will get nothing. when you `print query`, you will get `None` value. (Which may cause serious problem)

---

To make your code have correct behavior, you should make `another fake function` to send fake GET query.

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getIndex():
    query = request.form.get('query')
    return render_template('index.html',query=query)

@app.route("/<fake_query>")
def _getIndex(fake_query):
    query = fake_query
    return query

@app.route("/search_info")
def search_info():
    fake_query = 'whatever'
    string = _getIndex(fake_query)
    print string
    ...
```

---

About @Naishy's solution

Yes or No.

Session is a common way to solve this problem, ONLY after you have queried. But I did not see any description of that.

**Since your description is not completed**, if Session can solve you problem, I will delete this answer.